# warden Magento 2 multi store error Undefined index: MAGE_RUN_CODE

Tags: magento2.4, warden

I am facing following error :

```
MAGE_RUN_CODE in /var/www/html/app/etc/stores.php on line 12
```

I am using warden for local setup.

Answer (score 0):

In OP post apache vhost config is incorrect:

> SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE frenchstore_view;
>
> SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;

Parameters should be in double quotes and no semicolons.

Correct one:

> SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE "frenchstore_view"
>
> SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE "store"

Comment: I Tried this solution available on stack but its also not working

Comment: Create a new directory for store2 and copy the .htaccess and index.php into that new directory. Then update /store2/index.php to set the website code and update the line require _DIR_ . '/../../app/bootstrap.php'; to go up one directory. This way when you hit http://192.168.1.179:8090/store2 it will start at your new directory and index.php file